# For loop not working with js map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to print array in html, but my for loop is not working. I am trying to get the length of `dataArrayNew` but its not returning back where my for loop is added. If i `console.log(dataArrayNew.title);` , I am able to see the correct result. I am also attaching the print screen of my browser console. 
[image: below is my code -]

```
var dataArrayNew = [];

function fetch_section_data_1(){

var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
    dataArrayNew = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));   
    console.log(dataArrayNew.title);
    //lengtharray = dataArrayNew.length;
    //console.log(lengtharray);
    //return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});

var $table = $( "<table></table>" );
for(i=0;i<dataArrayNew.length;i++){
    var array_no = dataArrayNew[i];
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( array_no.title ) );
    $table.append( $line );
    console.log(dataArrayNew.title);
}

$table.appendTo(document.body);

}
```

Comment: Your `.map()` callback doesn't have a `return` statement. It should. Add `console.log(dataArray)` after the `.map()` and you'll see why.

Comment: i uncommented my return statement and added what you suggested, i can see this in my console - `https://www.dropbox.com/s/nexj0maebb3xm35/Screenshot%202017-05-17%2008.36.13.png?dl=0`   but still for loop not working

Comment: ok it worked , if i click on the title, how can i get its corresponding id from array, please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot see the `length` property is because you are reassigning `dataArrayNew` from an array to a result `JSON.parse` which is an object, and objects do not have the property `length`. Instead of reassigning the value of `dataArrayNew`, why don't you push the value of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))` to it, like so:

```
dataArrayNew.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
```

So your code should look something like this:

```js
var dataArrayNew = [];

function fetch_section_data_1(){

  var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
    return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
  });

  var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
    var currIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));   
    console.log(currIn);
    // push data to dataArrayNew
    dataArrayNew.push(currIn);
    //lengtharray = dataArrayNew.length;
    //console.log(lengtharray);
     //return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  });

  var $table = $( "<table></table>" );
  
  // You should be able to get the length here now
  for(var i = 0; i < dataArrayNew.length; i++){
      var array_no = dataArrayNew[i];
      var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
      $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( array_no.title ) );
      $table.append( $line );
      console.log(dataArrayNew.title);
  }

  $table.appendTo(document.body);

}
```

Comment: Yeah I did something similar, I just used dataArray itself after the map function, how can I console.log the id of the title I clicked

Comment: In that case, it would be `console.log(currIn.title)`

Comment: How to add click on title to get corresponding id

Comment: You probably need an event handler for that. Look up onClick on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick